# Displaying Quotation Mark Characters while retrieving from in Database to php

Tags: php, html, sql

I am storing large amounts of text in a database. The problem is that when I try to store quotation marks (‘ ’ “ ” not " ') they store in the database fine although do not show when I show the text from the database.!

I have tried changing collation in sql to utf8_unicode_ci,still not changing

(‘ ’ “ ” not " ')  are replaced by a questain mark within a square black box

## Column  Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action

```
     2  qr_topics   text    utf8_unicode_ci     No  None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run your database return through [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities) before displaying it!

```
$results = $pdo->fetchAll();

foreach($results as $result) {
    echo htmlentities($result['fieldQuotesAndOtherGoodies']);
}
```

Not only is this good practice (especially when working with different charsets or with brackets, `<` and `>`, which you have to encode because they will otherwise be interpreted as HTML tags), this is also a very important for security. Your site can be vulnerable to XSS (and therefore CSRF) attacks without the encoding of user data retrieved from the database.

Just for reference: the solution was to simply add a meta tag that ensured the HTML delivered was interpreted as UTF-8 by the browser:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

Comment: data is displayed using <td align="center" bgcolor="#F3F3F3"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font></td>
<td valign="top" ><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font></td>
<td valign="top" ><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td>
<td valign="top" ><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f4; ?></font></td>
How can i implement your idea

Comment: @RachelAndrew Place an `htmlentities()` around `$f1`, `$f2`, etc. So they should look like `htmlentities($f1)`, etc. Also, you should really consider using CSS instead of those messy deprecated font tags.

Comment: hii i updated it as <td valign="top" ><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo htmlentities ($f2); ?></font></td> but no effect

Comment: In the HTML that you are delivering this with do you have `<meta charset="UTF-8" />" in the `<head>`?

Answer (score 1):

mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8, NAMES utf8');

it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

make sure you insert your codes through htmlentities(). and while retriving it use html_entity_decode(). I agree to @PhpMycoder. use character set "utf-8" or any you like but pass the same to the function.

while sending to the server use

```
htmlentities ($_POST['textarea'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');

and while retriving

html_entity_decode($_POST['textarea'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
```